# How to get name of Financial Type ID?

Tags: civireport, custom-reports, financial-types

I am adding some custom code to the Bookkeeping Report so that each Financial Type's sub total is added to the bottom in the statistics. I have successfully done so, but I can't figure out how to list the name of the Financial Type ID instead of the ID itself.

For instance it is currently listed as 6: $300, 17: $540, etc. I would rather have it listed as: Event Income: $300, Fundraisers: $540, etc. I know this is listed in the table civicrm_financial_type and I can manually build it into the function; however, I did not know if there was an API or a function already built that returned the name of the ID.

[image: custom bookkeeping statistics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a FinancialType API which returns the name with the ID, for example:

```
$financialTypeName = civicrm_api3('FinancialType', 'Getvalue', array('id' => $financialTypeId, 'return' => 'name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function used in the Bookkeeping report to do this:

```
CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::financialType()
```

See e.g.

```
  public function alterDisplay(&$rows) {
    $contributionTypes = CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::financialType();
...
      // handle financial type id
      if ($value = CRM_Utils_Array::value('civicrm_line_item_financial_type_id', $row)) {
        $rows[$rowNum]['civicrm_line_item_financial_type_id'] = $contributionTypes[$value];
      }
```